# How do I delete a job listing?

Tags: support, jobs

I can't figure out how to delete a job listing. The one I want to delete is listed under "Previous Listings" on my Stack Overflow Careers employer account page. I have never and don't intend to publish the listing. I think it is just a draft.

The instructions [here](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/support) (under "Need to edit or remove a job listing?") didn't work for me... I don't see an edit link. I do see a "manage listing" link, but I don't see a way to delete the listing from *that* page either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drafts have been an oversight to how the rest of the listings work. We're working on rectifying that. If you'll e-mail careers@stackoverflow.com, I can look up your account and delete that for you.